# Different Behavior for Same Class depending on Dependencies?

Tags: java, dependencies, sbt, swagger

I'm confused as to why I'm observing different outputs of a method call depending on whether an additional library is included.

I observed different outcomes when parsing a Swagger v1.2 Doc with and without the `swagger-compat-spec-parser` library.

Note that, in the following output, I'm running the Scala programming language's REPL.

**Parse Swagger Doc to `null` without `swagger-compat-spec-parser` library**

```
$cat build.sbt
 libraryDependencies += "io.swagger" % "swagger-parser" % "1.0.17"
$sbt console

scala> import io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser
import io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser

scala> "/Users/Kevin/Workspace/project/src/test/resources/api-docs-swagger-v1.2"
res0: String = /Users/Kevin/Workspace/project/src/test/resources/api-docs-swagger-v1.2

scala> new SwaggerParser().read(res0)
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
reading from /Users/Kevin/Workspace/project/src/test/resources/api-docs-swagger-v1.2
reading from /Users/Kevin/Workspace/project/src/test/resources/api-docs-swagger-v1.2
res1: io.swagger.models.Swagger = null
```

**Parse Swagger Doc to non-null result with `swagger-compat-spec-parser` library**

```
$cat build.sbt
 libraryDependencies += "io.swagger" % "swagger-parser" % "1.0.17"
 libraryDependencies += "io.swagger" % "swagger-compat-spec-parser" % "1.0.17"
$sbt console

scala> import io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser
import io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser

scala> "/Users/Kevin/Workspace/project/src/test/resources/api-docs-swagger-v1.2"
res0: String = /Users/Kevin/Workspace/project/src/test/resources/api-docs-swagger-v1.2

scala> new SwaggerParser().read(res0)
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
reading from /Users/Kevin/Workspace/project/src/test/resources/api-docs-swagger-v1.2
reading from /Users/Kevin/Workspace/project/src/test/resources/api-docs-swagger-v1.2
res1: io.swagger.models.Swagger = io.swagger.models.Swagger@5876ed9a
```

Why would the same (I presume) class's `read` method vary depending on whether another dependency is present?

Comment: The full, specific question, should be posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Swagger related.

Behavior is OK, even maybe not documented (at least not in source code). Take a look at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/blob/master/modules/swagger-parser/src/main/java/io/swagger/parser/SwaggerParser.java#L55

More precisely at line 64 where Swagger reads location, but only when it is URL.

Hence your example runs until line 72, where the extensions are used. The extensions are provided via getExtensions() at line 60 (definition at line 169).

As you can see they are loaded at runtime via ServiceLoader, i.e. when not provided no parsing :)

Hope that clears the behavior. But you can test your 2nd example pointing Swagger to not existing file to see where it blows out and you'll get:

```
scala> "/Users/IMNotKevin/Thus/Api/Does/Not/Exist"
res0: String = /Users/IMNotKevin/Thus/Api/Does/Not/Exist

scala> new SwaggerParser().read(res0)
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
reading from /Users/IMNotKevin/Thus/Api/Does/Not/Exist
reading from /Users/IMNotKevin/Thus/Api/Does/Not/Exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/IMNotKevin/Thus/Api/Does/Not/Exist (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:708)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:1861)
   at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.readResourceListing(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:139)
   at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.read(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:74)
   at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser.read(SwaggerParser.java:73)
   at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser.read(SwaggerParser.java:52)
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

@Teliakto is correct.  Per the [README](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser#extensions), you MUST load the `swagger-compat-spec-parser` if you want to load a 1.2 spec.  This is done via SPI.